# How can I list all the meta in a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta

I have a site that has custom post types and corresponding taxonomies.
I'm trying to create a new archive page for each taxonomy.  The problem is that I don't know how to find the actual name of the meta fields for the custom taxonomy.

Each taxonomy can have an image and a description.  I'd like to put those 2 fields at the top of the archive page. So the first step seems to be figuring out how to idenitfy the actual names of the meta fields.
I tried this within the loop of the archive page template.  It displays empty though:

```
$display_type = get_term_meta( $term->term_id );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($display_type);
echo '</pre>';
```

Is there any way to list all the post meta for each term in the taxonomy on an archive page?